# How to remove all javascript in joomla ?

Tags: php, joomla

I using code here

```
<head>
...
<?php 
$user =& JFactory::getUser(); 
if ($user->get('guest') == 1) { 
   $headerstuff = $this->getHeadData(); 
   $headerstuff['scripts'] = array(); $this->setHeadData($headerstuff); 
} 
?>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
</head>
```

But when run code is template load all javascript, how to fix it remove all javasccript in header in template joomla

Comment: what's for do you need this? Do you want to move all js calls to the footer of the page? - there are a plenty of native joomla plugins for all those types of optimisations

Answer (score 5):

To remove a script you can use in your template:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();    
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/system/js/mootools-core.js']);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the unwanted scripts from your Joomla site. You either try like this

```
<?php 
         //get the all the script declarations
         $document = JFactory::getDocument(); 
         $headData = $document->getHeadData();
         $scripts = $headData['scripts'];

         //if you want to remove all the script
         unset($scripts);

         //if you want to remove specific file then try like this
         unset($scripts['/media/system/js/mootools-core.js']);
?>
```

Or try like this

```
//if you want to remove all the script
<?php unset($this->_scripts); ?>

//if you want to remove specific file then try like this
<?php unset($this->_scripts['/media/system/js/mootools-core.js']); ?>
```

You can apply any method before `<jdoc:include type="head" />` . It will remove all the scripts.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->_scripts = array(); // just clear array
```

before this line

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to remove all javascript that is betwween the `head` tags?

If so, you need to find the folder of your template in `joomla_root\templates\` and open `index.php` in it(ex: `joomla_root\templates\beez5\index.php`) (I recommend taking a backup first). Then remove everything between `head` tags that start with:

`<script type="text/javascript"`

You might also need to remove `$doc->addScript(` lines..

Answer (score 0):

The line you have provided gets data from another file, so it will be the other file that contains the lines of code to embed javascript files. Simply search for

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and

```
$document->addScript(.....);
```

and you might also find something like this

```
$document->addScriptDeclaration($variable);
```